# What is the font called for the "Spider man" portion of the "Friendly Neighborhood Spider Man" comic title?

Tags: font-identification

[Here's an example of the title I'm asking about](https://www.kindpng.com/imgv/TJiTixb_friendly-neighborhood-spider-man-wiki-friendly-neighborhood-spider/)

Answer (score 0):

"Spider-Man" is a custom typeface.

You may be able to find "knock off" fonts that have tried to mimic it. However, similar to many logotypes, it was never an actual font for the comic books, it was art.